# Sunrise time across the globe?

Tags: astronomy, orbital-motion, kinematics, earth

This question is more astronomy related, I started thinking when I heard from one of my friends living in [Jiamusi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jiamusi), that Sun rise at 02:00 and sets at 14:00, I know that this place is more near to north pole but why sunrise time so different there?

I appreciate your time and answers.

Comment: AM and PM isn't used with 24-hour format..

Answer (score 2):

This happens because the earth is slightly tilted (22 1/2 degrees).

The tilt means different parts of the Earth are exposed to the sun for varying times during different seasons. In the equator, the day/night variance is very less while at the poles it is very significant (on the North Pole, Day and Night last 6 months each).